# Selecting existing and missing records according to another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got two tables:

```
LANGUAGES
  LANGUAGE_ID  number(4),
  LANG_NAME    varchar2(30)

LABELS 
  LANGUAGE_ID  number(4),
  TEXT_ID      varchar2(20),
  LABEL_TEXT   varchar2(100)
```

With the following entries:

```
LANGUAGES:
  LANGUAGE_ID | LANG_NAME
  -----------------------
            1 | german
            2 | english
            3 | spanish
            4 | italian

LABELS:
  LANGUAGE_ID | TEXT_ID | LABEL_TEXT
  -----------------------------------
            1 | A       | Lorem ipsum
            2 | A       | Lorem ipsum
            1 | B       | Lorem ipsum
            2 | B       | Lorem ipsum
            3 | B       | Lorem ipsum
```

My target would now be selecting all labels, and for all languages where a label has not yet been entered, an empty record. The result should be this:

```
LANGUAGE_ID | TEXT_ID | LABEL_TEXT
----------------------------------
          1 | A       | Lorem ipsum
          2 | A       | Lorem ipsum
          3 | A       | 
          4 | A       | 
          1 | B       | Lorem ipsum
          2 | B       | Lorem ipsum
          3 | B       | Lorem ipsum
          4 | B       |
```

How can I achieve this with a well-performing statement using Oracle SQL?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT a.language_id, a.text_id, l.label_text
  FROM
(
  SELECT language_id, text_id
    FROM languages CROSS JOIN
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT text_id FROM labels
 ) q) a LEFT JOIN labels l 
    ON a.language_id = l.language_id
   AND a.text_id = l.text_id
ORDER BY a.text_id, a.language_id
```

Output:

```
| LANGUAGE_ID | TEXT_ID |   LABEL_TEXT |
----------------------------------------
|           1 |       A |  Lorem ipsum |
|           2 |       A |  Lorem ipsum |
|           3 |       A |       (null) |
|           4 |       A |       (null) |
|           1 |       B |  Lorem ipsum |
|           2 |       B |  Lorem ipsum |
|           3 |       B | Lorem ipsumh |
|           4 |       B |       (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d908/1)** demo

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but on 9 Languages and about 80'000 labels, it gets massively imperformant. Is there a way to optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

***this is what you want you want i guess.***

```
select a.language_id,b.text_id,b.label_text
from languages a left join labels b
on a.language_id=b.language_id
```

Comment: This won't give results for nonexistent combinations `language_id,text_id`